# How to set value and populate dropdown using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-options

How to set value and populate dropdown using angularjs?

I have succesfully setup the option in both dropdowns.

In my dropdown one is dependent to another

Suppose in my database Parent name is Sally and child name is SallyChild2,when an updating this page, i need to populate the entire data 
with select this particular parent name as Sally and childname as SallyChild2

My database value is Parent - Sally and Child - SallyChild2

So i want to change Child - SallyChild1

So I hard coded as this wat but not working

```
$scope.selectedParent="Sally";
$scope.selectedChild="SallyChild2";
```

But its not working

Here is my complete code

This is my script.js

script.js

```
var app=angular.module('TestApp', ['angular.filter','ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('category',
    {
    views : {   
        "body" :
    {
        url : '/category',
        templateUrl : 'category.html',
        controller : 'TestController'
    }
    }   

    })

    .state('category.subcategory',
    {
    url : '/subcategory',
    views : {                              
    "subbody@category" :
    {
    templateUrl : 'sample.html',
    controller : 'SampleController'              
    }
    }
    })
});

app.controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope,$state)
{
    alert("This is MainController")

    $scope.getCategory=function()
    {
    $state.go('category');
    }


}

app.controller('TestController', TestController);

//TestController.$inject['dataservice'];

function TestController($scope, $state){


    $scope.data=[
     {
      "parentName": "George",
      "childName": "George Child1"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "FollyChild1"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "childName": "Sally Child1"          
     },

     {
      "parentName": "George",
      "childName": "GeorgChild2"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "FollyChild2"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Folly",
      "childName": "Infant Food"          
     },
     {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "childName": "SallyChild2"          
     }
    ];

    $scope.selectedParent="Sally";
    $scope.selectedChild="SallyChild2";

    function onParentChange(parent){
      if(!parent){
    $scope.child = undefined;
      }
    }


    $scope.getValue=function()
    {
    alert("Call to Sample Controller")

    var currentState = $state.current.name;
    var targetState = 'category.subcategory';

    if(currentState === targetState)
      $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
    else
    $state.go(targetState);
    $state.go(".subcategory");

    //$state.go('category.subcategory');
    }
}


app.controller('SampleController', SampleController);

function SampleController($scope,$state)
{
    alert("This is SampleController")

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script>    
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-filter.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <a href="#" ng-click="getCategory()">Click to Category</a>
        <div ui-view="body"></div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

category.html

```
  <div>    
    <hr>

    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Parent</b></label>
      <select ng-model="selectedParent"
        ng-init="selectedParent = null"
        ng-change="onParentChange(selectedParent)"
        class="form-control" id="data">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in data | orderBy:'parentName'| groupBy:'parentName'">{{key}}</option>           
      </select>
    </div>              
      </form>  
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-3">      
      <form>    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Child Names</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="childnames" ng-model="child" 
        ng-disabled="!selectedParent"
        ng-options="data.childName for data in data| filter: {parentName:selectedParent} | removeWith:{childName : 'Infant Food'}" ng-change="getValue()">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
      </select>
    </div>          

      </form>     
  </div>
    <div ui-view="subbody"></div>
  </div>
```

sample.html

```
<div>
    Sample Controller
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some jsfiddle example?

Comment: Your ask is not very clear. Is your scenario that the first dropdown should have the parent's name and the 2nd dropdown will the children name. On changing the parent dropdown; the children dropdown should also change for the selected parent? And it would be good if you can add some working fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: @Pratik Bhattacharya its working fine, when an updating these dropdown got an issue.Suppose in my db Parent name is Sally and child name is SallyChild2. When a edit button is clicked i want to show the dropdown as Parent Sally and child name SallyChild2.Please help me.I am new in this .I copied my entire code

Comment: Now its now only show  Select in both Parent and Childname .I want to set the value

Comment: @Pratik Bhattacharya Please helpme ji.I dont know how to use JFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have really is an array of children.  So, you set up your `<select>` tag like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedChild" ng-options="child as child.childName for child in children"></select>
```

Now, your `selectedChild` model contains both parent name and child name.  You do not need to separate the model into two.

The second part, in order to set your initial values, you need to make use of `angular.equals()` to your SallyChild2 target.  Like this:

```
var target = {
      "parentName": "Sally",
      "childName": "SallyChild2"
};

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.children.length; ++i) {
  if(angular.equals($scope.children[i], target)) {
    $scope.children[i] = target;

    $scope.selectedChild = $scope.children[i];
  }
}
```

Here is a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/60ajq6KBmUKXuPeT6yI2?p=preview

---

To do this with two select dropdowns, simply do:

```
//parents dropdown
<select ng-model="selectedParent" ng-options="parent as parent.parentName for parent in data | unique: 'parentName'"></select>

//children dropdown
<select ng-model="selectedChild" ng-options="child as child.childName for child in getChildren(selectedParent)"></select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.getChildren = function(parent) {
    var children = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; ++) {
        if($scope.data[i].parentName === parent {
            children.push($scope.data[i]);
        }
    }

    return children;
}
```

Comment: thankyou but i need two dropdowns if selecting parent the corresponding children should be shown in inside childname dropdown.Please help me.And one more thing actually parentname and childname is not static one its getting from database so it should be dynamic data

Comment: That's easy to do too.  `<select ng-options="parent as parent.parentName for parent in parents | unique: 'parentName'">`  Then, for your second select box, just do `<select ng-options="child as child.childName for child in getChildren(selectedParent)">`.  `getChildren(selectedParent)` is a function that would return an array of children belonging to that parent.

Comment: in my code it shows only select option first not coming Sally and SallyChild2